# Proving Polynomial with binomial coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials

Let $P(X)\in \mathbb Q[X]$ whereby $P(\lambda) \in \mathbb Z$ , $\forall \lambda \in \mathbb N$. Show that there are $a_{1},...,a_{r}$ $\in \mathbb Z$ and $n_{1},...,n_{r}$ $\in \mathbb N$ such that

$P(X)=a_{1}\binom{X}{n_{1}}+...+a_{r}\binom{X}{n_{r}}$

I am pretty stumped by the challenge question we received on our last question paper. I always find proofs to assert that there are such families $(a_{r})_{r}$ and $(n_{r})_{r}$ extremely difficult. Is induction even a starting point here given that $(a_{r})_{r} \in \mathbb Z$? How can we assert anything about the degree of the polynomial $P(X)$ without more information on the nature of $(n_{r})_{r}$?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: First observe that the polynomial $\binom{X}{n}$ has degree $n$ and returns integers when evaluated at the natural numbers. Second, observe that $Dp(x)=p(x+1)-p(x)$ has degree $n-1$, if $p$ has degree $n$, and also returns integers at the naturals if $p$ did so in the first place. Third, observe that $D\binom{X}{n}=\binom{X}{n-1}$. Last, write $P$ as a linear combination of $\binom{X}{n}$ and compute the coefficients by taking $D$-erivatives (starting from $D$-erivative of order $\deg(P)-1$ and going down) and evaluating at $X=0$, to show that the coefficients are integers.